# Passing the Lower Cholesky Factor of an Eigen matrix as a function parameter

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I would like to preface this by saying I am a C++ novice, so please be verbose in your comments and/or suggestions.

I am trying to refactor some code. One of the operations I perform involves taking a (memoized) `Eigen::LLT<Eigen::MatrixXd>` type object from a list and performing some calculations with it.

I would like to refactor this calculation into a smaller function, but I am having trouble passing the `Eigen::LLT<Eigen::MatrixXd>` type as a parameter while adhering to (*my admittedly wobbly understanding of*) the advice in the [Eigen documentation here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html).

I have tried the following:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <Eigen/LU>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <math.h>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/SpecialFunctions>

Eigen::MatrixXd conditionalCov(
    Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd> kxstarxstar,
    Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::LLT<Eigen::MatrixXd>> lxx,
    Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd> kxxstar
    )
{
    return (
        kxstarxstar.array() - (kxxstar.transpose() * lxx.solve(kxxstar)).array()
        ).matrix().selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>();
}
```

But this does not compile because of the type definition for `lxx`, namely `Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::LLT<Eigen::MatrixXd>>`, is wrong. GCC says:

```
[<path_to_file>] error: ‘IsVectorAtCompileTime’ is not a member of ‘const Eigen::LLT<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 1>’
        5 |     Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::LLT<Eigen::MatrixXd>> lxx,
```

What should the type of `lxx` (the lower Cholesky factor) be here to avoid creation of temporary matrices when calling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the `LLT` object as a standard C++ constant reference.

Passing `kxstarxstar` and `kxxstar` by `Eigen::Ref` also only makes sense, if you intend to pass sub-blocks of other matrices. If not, just pass them as `const Eigen::MatrixXd &`. If you want to pass them as  `Eigen::Ref`, it is recommended to pass that itself as `const &`:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd conditionalCov(
    const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd>& kxstarxstar,
    const Eigen::LLT<Eigen::MatrixXd> &lxx,
    const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd>& kxxstar
    )
```

N.B.: Inside your function there is no need to convert between Matrix and Array types, just the following should give the same result:

```
return (
    kxstarxstar - kxxstar.transpose() * lxx.solve(kxxstar)
    ).selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>();
```